# Embedding a Google Group into a website

Tags: iframe, embedding, google-groups

I'm embedding a group into a (non-Google) website and getting a blank page.

I've added the code that the 'Manage your Group' gives, which is below.

```
<iframe id="forum_embed"
  src="javascript:void(0)"
  scrolling="no"
  frameborder="0"
  width="900"
  height="700">
</iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('forum_embed').src =
 'https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/?place=forum/the-sophia-club'
 + '&showsearch=true&showpopout=true&showtabs=false'
 + '&parenturl=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);
```

I have tried removing the &parenturl with no success.

I also tried saving the code on a simple html doc by itself, and it still gives me a blank page.

Here's the code for the single page...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>
<body>
<p>Testing</p>
<iframe id="forum_embed"
  src="javascript:void(0)"
  scrolling="no"
  frameborder="0"
  width="900"
  height="700">
</iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('forum_embed').src =
 'https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/?place=forum/the-sophia-club'
 + '&showsearch=true&showpopout=true&showtabs=false'
 + '&parenturl=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas on what is going wrong??

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your document is xhtml instead of html. The two standards are different and Google doesn't seem to like xhtml.

xhtml seems to be dead unfortunately, so try changing to html5. The only required change should be in the doctype declaration.

Also, the embedding didn't work when I opened the page using my web browser pointing to a local directory. However it did work when I uploaded the page to the web server.